# How to fadeOut or hide a kendoDateTimePicker with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

With the controller I passed a date in the controller and i have to hide it. I tried serveral ways but i cant make it work

```
if ($('#Pre_1660').data("kendoDateTimePicker")) {           
                console.log($('#Pre_1660').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value());
               if ($('#Pre_1660').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value() != null) {
                    $('#Pre_1660').fadeOut();
                    $('.PreguntaBody1660').fadeOut();
                    $('#PreguntaBody1660').hide();
                    $('#PreguntaBody1660').hide();
                    
              }
}
```

I also tried to see the value

```
if ($('#PA010').data("kendoDateTimePicker")) {
                console.log($('#PA010').data("kendoDateTimePicker").value());
}
```

[image]

I can hide the hole div and the label with this

```
$('#PreguntaBody1660').fadeOut();
$('#Nom_1660').fadeOut();
```

The problem is, the if

Answer (score 0):

Try this one [kendo datetime close](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker/methods/close)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this way everything can be hidden, so you dont see the tag either

```
$('#PreguntaBody1660').fadeOut();
$('#Nom_1660').fadeOut();
```

And in case you need an if before:

```
$('#PreguntaPA010').find('input[name^=Pre]').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
```